# I dropped the null values in the beginning but after one hot encoding there are null values present

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, isnull

`enter code here`I read the dataset and checked for null values, it showed there were two rows with null values, so I dropped those two rows. then checked for any null values, but it showed no null values, so I proceeded with the next steps. my data set contains a gender column for which I did one hot encoding and converted other categorical features with respective encoders. I changed the index order to bring object columns to one side and integer columns to the other side using indexing. But now, when checking for null values, the now converted gender column has null values in them. how to proceed from here...

dataset link - https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rkiattisak/salaly-prediction-for-beginer

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
df=df.dropna()

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc=OneHotEncoder()
one_enc_data= pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['Gender'])
enc_data = pd.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(df[['Gender']]).toarray())

df=df.join(enc_data)
from category_encoders import TargetEncoder
encoder = TargetEncoder()
df['job_title_encoded'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Job Title'], df['Salary'])

df=df.iloc[:,[1,3,0,6,7,2,4,8,5]]
```

[image: [null values]]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[tail(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvhq0.png)
I wanted to try filling the values but I'm unsure if it is possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question is not related to OH-encoding or data science, please adjust the tags

Comment: Please do not provide code as screenshots

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Can you show us row indexed 373 and 374 by using df.tail(2) ?

Comment: Hey! I added an image of the df.tail(2)

Comment: Hey! I added the code and changed the tags!

Comment: This looks like a problem with the `join`: the dummies get made into a dataframe with default index, but your main `df` still has the original index (0...374 less the two dropped rows).

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I solve this problem? Thank you!